# How to create partial copy of DB Objects (tables, functions, stored procedures, etc) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ddl

For a join project with a 3rd party I need to build a new database in SQL Server (2014SP2), which will include only main objects from our current one and without any data, apart from some basic settings I will **INSERT INTO** later.

I maintain our **DDL** scripts on GitHub, so on a daily basis every new script will be saved there as well as on our local SQL Server with .sql extension and then will be picked up and processed by my stored procedure mySP across our test DB's. Once everyone is happy and things have been tested, I will send the script to our DBA's to apply in live.

In order to address this new request I was thinking to implement same approach:

1. To have all the relevant scripts saved on the new SQL Server.
2. Run stored procedure mySP, which will pick them up
   and process one by one: will execute the scripts, record the
   errors (I already know there will be some, e.g. foreign keys on
   tables, which may not exist yet), send me an email with the list of
   errors and then I will have to manually fix them (e.g. re-build
   those foreign keys).

My question if there is any better approach, please?

Example of my current process :

Step 1 - save a script with .sql extension on SQL Server. example for such a script is below

```
/*********************************************************************/
--   Date   |Developer's Name    | Version | Description 
--27/04/2018| Mr Smith           |    12   | Added new column myColumn
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD myColumn BIT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

Step 2 - my stored procedure is scheduled to run every hour and will pick up all the .sql files from the predefined location and process them, sending me the email. The script is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3309/1

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you be testing to avoid things like problems with foreign keys before you go live?

Comment: I will know of FK issues straight away from my stored procedure, prior testing - it will send me a nice HTML style email with all the errors, file names causing the errors and which DB had this error. I will find a referral to the script in Step 2 above. My question if there is better way to deploy the scripts.